# Why does intializing array with structs requires specifying the struct name

Tags: c++, aggregate, initializer-list, stdarray

Why does this code produce compile time error?

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <string_view>

using namespace std::string_view_literals;

enum class my_enum : std::size_t {
    first = 0,
    second,
    third,

    COUNT,
};

struct my_enum_str_pair {
    std::string_view str;
    my_enum command;
};

constexpr 
std::array<my_enum_str_pair, static_cast<std::size_t>(my_enum::COUNT)> 
my_enum_str_pairs = {
    { "first"sv, my_enum::first },
    { "second"sv, my_enum::second }, // error: excess elements in struct initializer
    { "third"sv, my_enum::third },
};
```

But if we change it to

```
...

constexpr 
std::array<my_enum_str_pair, static_cast<std::size_t>(my_enum::COUNT)> 
my_enum_str_pairs = {
    my_enum_str_pair{ "first"sv, my_enum::first },
    { "second"sv, my_enum::second },
    { "third"sv, my_enum::third },
};
```

Is compiles just fine?

https://godbolt.org/z/pi2j8a

Comment: An extra pair of braces also helps: `my_enum_str_pairs = {{   { "first"sv, my_enum::first }, ... }};` I don't remember why, but `std::array` needs this extra pair sometimes.

Comment: the usual method for dealing with `std::array` initialization problems is: keep adding more braces until it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a pair of brackets.

```cpp
constexpr 
std::array<my_enum_str_pair, static_cast<std::size_t>(my_enum::COUNT)> 
my_enum_str_pairs = 
{{
    { "first"sv, my_enum::first },
    { "second"sv, my_enum::second }, // error: excess elements in struct initializer
    { "third"sv, my_enum::third }
}};
```

Comment: But why is it required?

Comment: std::array contains an internal array. 
https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/std/array.html#std::array::_M_elems

To init a C array you do:  int foo[] = {};

Comment: However that array is inside std::array, hence the need for the second set of brackets.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is explained by the following quote from the C++ 17 Standard (11.6.1 Aggregates)

> 12 **Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows**. If the
>   initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding
>   comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the elements
>   of a subaggregate; it is erroneous  for there to be more
>   initializer-clauses than elements. If, however, the initializer-list
>   for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only enough
>   initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the elements
>   of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are left to
>   initialize the next element of the aggregate of which the current
>   subaggregate is an element.

The std::array is an aggregate that includes another aggregate.

```
constexpr 
std::array<my_enum_str_pair, static_cast<std::size_t>(my_enum::COUNT)> 
my_enum_str_pairs = {
    { "first"sv, my_enum::first },
    { "second"sv, my_enum::second }, // error: excess elements in struct initializer
    { "third"sv, my_enum::third },
};
```

So the compiler considers the first left brace in the first initializer

```
{ "first"sv, my_enum::first },
```

^^^

As the initializer of the internal sub-aggregate (that is usually an array) of the aggregate `std::array`. After this list it encounters the second list

```
{ "second"sv, my_enum::second }
```

but does not found another sub-object of the `std::array`. So the compiler issues an error.

If you enclose these lists in braces

```
constexpr 
std::array<my_enum_str_pair, static_cast<std::size_t>(my_enum::COUNT)> 
my_enum_str_pairs = {
{
    { "first"sv, my_enum::first },
    { "second"sv, my_enum::second }, // error: excess elements in struct initializer
    { "third"sv, my_enum::third },
}
};
```

then the compiler considers all sub-list as elements of the internal sub-aggregate and uses this sub-list as initializers of the constructor of the class std::pair.

In the second case the left braces

```
constexpr 
std::array<my_enum_str_pair, static_cast<std::size_t>(my_enum::COUNT)> 
my_enum_str_pairs = {
                   ^^^^ 
    my_enum_str_pair{ "first"sv, my_enum::first },
    { "second"sv, my_enum::second },
    { "third"sv, my_enum::third },
};
```

starts the initializer list of the internal sub-aggregate eliding one more braces for it.

To make it more clear consider three examples of the same program with different approaches to initializations.

The first program

```
#include <iostream>

struct Int
{
    Int( int x ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
};

template <size_t N>
struct Array
{
    Int a[N];
};

int main() 
{
    Array<3> a = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler will issue an error because the first open brace before 1

```
    Array<3> a = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };
                  ^^^
```

is considered by the compiler as an initializer list of the internal aggregate `Int a[N]`.

If to add one more pair of braces like

```
#include <iostream>

struct Int
{
    Int( int x ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
};

template <size_t N>
struct Array
{
    Int a[N];
};

int main() 
{
    Array<3> a = { { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } } };

    return 0;
}
```

Then in this case the first open braces will be the following

```
    Array<3> a = { { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } } };
                  ^^^
```

and the elements inside these braces will be considered as initializers of the internal aggregate `Int a[N]`.

In the third program

```
#include <iostream>

struct Int
{
    Int( int x ) : x( x ) {}
    int x;
};

template <size_t N>
struct Array
{
    Int a[N];
};

int main() 
{
    Array<3> a = { Int{ 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 } };

    return 0;
}
```

the initializer list does not start with an open brace for the internal aggregate Int a[N]. It starts from the casting expression

```
Int{ 1 }
```

So all other elements are considered by the compiler as initializers of the internal aggregate Int a[N]. So according to the quote the braces may be elided.

Comment: @S.M. I also think so.:)

Comment: @S.M. it wasn't like this when I accepted the answer and I don't want to change it now.